# How can i generate and download PDFs in Flask without saving them in my Webapp?

Tags: pdf, flask, reportlab

im trying to get a PDF with the ReportLab Module which works fine so far. My problem is that im saving the PDF with the .build()-method in my Webapps directory. What i want is that i can send the PDF for downloading without saving it before. That is somehow possible with the wkhtmltopdf module, but i dont want to use any other servers for this. 
The process would be like: User presses a button 'download as pdf', a pdf is generated and instant returned as a download without saving it first.
Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You want to create the PDF server side, return it to the client, without saving the PDF (for example, in S3)?

Yes, this is possible, you create the PDF in memory using

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
myPDF = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)
```

Then after creating your pdf you save it using

```
myPDF.save()
buffer.seek(0)
```

Then when you are ready to return the PDF as a reponse you can return it with:

```
response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format("myFile.pdf")
return response
```